SQL: How to declare AS before SELECT?
How can I rewrite
SELECT x, "noflowizts tidbits" AS n, z, bloflvopitz AS b

Just as
SELECT x, y, n, b

Then I could even write
SELECT x, CONCAT(n, z), y

For this one query, I simply want to have a clearer way of writing it, where I can rearrange the terms at ease without careful editing work.
It is great that we can declare aliases at the same time we SELECT them, but sometimes I would like to do it separately. Yes, all I need to affect is just this one query.

You could rely on a common table expression (CTE), which allows defining the column aliases outside of the CTE code block itself.  Consider:
WITH cte (a, b, c) AS (
    SELECT 1, 2, 3
)

SELECT a, b, c
FROM cte;

To change the alias names, you only need to modify the WITH clause itself, but the SQL code inside the CTE can remain the same.
Demo
